# VS2010: .DEF file not deleted on clean?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker

I'm developing a C project within a solution of multiple projects in Visual Studio 2010. So far building worked like a charm, but...

As I understand, DEF files are used for linking. As I changed the method declarations in some of my code, the code would no longer build, because of linking problems. I tried cleaning, building and rebuilding and the DEF file would not be changed. Is that normal? It doesn't seem to depend on whether I choose the release or debug config? Or am I doing something wrong?

*P.S. Sorry if that should be a too easy question, but I really can't find anything on that and I really don't understand...*

Comment: When building I get the message that "Not re-generating MMDATA.DEF, file already exists". And I should mention that it works if I delete the def files manually, of course, because then they are re-generated. But I'm sure that's not the way to do it, right?

Comment: Getting a .def file deleted would normally be a disaster, they are hand-crafted with a great deal of effort if the DLL is not trivial.  Apparently, you've got some kind of build tool that auto-generates it.  If it pees on your leg about not wanting to overwrite a .def file then you'll have to delete it yourself in a pre-build event.

Comment: Ok! I didn't know that! Yes, my DEF file gets auto-generated. Ok, so I hope it stays something I only have to do very seldom ;-) Thanks a lot for clarifying!